# How to remove the label of scale label and tooltip on speedometer?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

i want to remove the label of scale label and tooltip on speedometer? I manage to remove the label between 0 and 200 but what i want is no label is label on the speedometer even the box field in middle of the speedometer. Please help. TQ.

Below is my code.

```js
$(function () {

    $('#container').highcharts({

        chart: {
            type: 'gauge',
            plotShadow: false
        },

        title: {
            text: ''
        },

        pane: {
            startAngle: -150,
            endAngle: 150,
            background: [{
                backgroundColor: {
                    linearGradient: { x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1 },
                    stops: [
                        [0, '#FFF'],
                        [1, '#333']
                    ]
                },
                borderWidth: 0,
                outerRadius: '109%'
            }, {
                backgroundColor: {
                    linearGradient: { x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1 },
                    stops: [
                        [0, '#333'],
                        [1, '#FFF']
                    ]
                },
                borderWidth: 1,
                outerRadius: '107%'
            }, {
                // default background
            }, {
                backgroundColor: '#DDD',
                borderWidth: 0,
                outerRadius: '50%',
                innerRadius: '48%'
            }]
        },

        // the value axis
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            max: 200,

            
            title: {
                text: ''
            },
            plotBands: [{
                from: 0,
                to: 120,
                color: '#55BF3B' // green
            }, {
                from: 120,
                to: 160,
                color: '#DDDF0D' // yellow
            }, {
                from: 160,
                to: 200,
                color: '#DF5353' // red
            }]
        },

        series: [{
            name: '',
            data: [80],
        }]

    },
    // Add some life
    function (chart) {
        
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 20px; max-width: 100px; height: 100px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can :

- add `credits: { enabled: false }` to remove that "Highcharts.com"
- add `yAxis: { labels: { enabled: false } }` to remove the scale label
- add `tooltip: {enabled: false }` to remove the tooltip

**Edit**: also add `dataLabels:{ enabled: false }` to your serie to hide the "80" label

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts

```js
$(function () {

    $('#container').highcharts({

        chart: {
            type: 'gauge',
            plotShadow: false
        },

        title: {
            text: ''
        },

        pane: {
            startAngle: -150,
            endAngle: 150,
            background: [{
                backgroundColor: {
                    linearGradient: { x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1 },
                    stops: [
                        [0, '#FFF'],
                        [1, '#333']
                    ]
                },
                borderWidth: 0,
                outerRadius: '109%'
            }, {
                backgroundColor: {
                    linearGradient: { x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1 },
                    stops: [
                        [0, '#333'],
                        [1, '#FFF']
                    ]
                },
                borderWidth: 1,
                outerRadius: '107%'
            }, {
                // default background
            }, {
                backgroundColor: '#DDD',
                borderWidth: 0,
                outerRadius: '50%',
                innerRadius: '48%'
            }]
        },
        // the value axis
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            max: 200,
            labels: { enabled: false },
            title: {
                text: ''
            },
            plotBands: [{
                from: 0,
                to: 120,
                color: '#55BF3B' // green
            }, {
                from: 120,
                to: 160,
                color: '#DDDF0D' // yellow
            }, {
                from: 160,
                to: 200,
                color: '#DF5353' // red
            }]
        },
        series: [{
            name: '',
            data: [80],
            dataLabels:{ enabled: false },
        }],
        tooltip: {enabled: false },
        credits: { enabled: false }
    },
    // Add some life
    function (chart) {
        
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 20px; max-width: 100px; height: 100px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```